# Isometries on the unit sphere

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-problems

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two Banach spaces, $S_{X}$ and $S_{Y}$ their unit spheres, and $f$ an onto isometry between $S_X$ and $S_Y$. Does it follow that $X$ and $Y$ are isometric?

Comment: I believe this is open when stated in full-generality, being sometimes referred to as Tingley's problem. I do not know the details here, but perhaps having this name to search for may help you out; for instance, the answer is apparently positive if $X$ or $Y$ is one of the classical sequence spaces

Comment: (I am assuming you are taking real scalars everywhere)

Comment: As of November 2018, the problem seems to be still open https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10674.pdf

Comment: Is there a reason why the insistence on real scalars? Doesn't the problem make sense for complex too?

Comment: Also, my question seems to be a tad weaker than Tingley's problem, no? $X$ and $Y$ may still be isometric, even if $f$ does not have an extension.

Comment: @Markus: There are many examples of complex Banach spaces that are not isomorphic as complex Banach spaces but are isometrically isomorphic as real Banach spaces.  See [MR0818448](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=818448).